# {"Object Reference Not Set to Instance of an Object."} ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, null

Just asking around for help to solve problems that for a beginner like me look cumbersome, even though it might not be the case. I did try to look for answers on Google to no avail. Without further introduction, please let me tell you more about the issue that I am having and the code that I am using.

I am using vb and this is the error that I get whenever I try to pass a value to another page

```
An exception of type System.NullReferenceException occurred but was not handled in user code
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to instance of an object.
  Source=Formulario
  StackTrace:
       in Formulario.InfoFormulario.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) en D: \Formulario\Formulario\InfoFormulario.aspx.vb:línea 8
       in System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
       in System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
       in System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
  InnerException:
```

The code that I am using to capture the origin page is the following:

```
   Public ReadOnly Property GetNombre() As String
        Get
            MsgBox("The value of " + TxtNombre.Text)
            Return TxtNombre.Text

        End Get
    End Property
```

The code that I am using to get the value is the following

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        LabelNombre.Text = (PreviousPage.GetNombre)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Someone please correct me if I am wrong, but I believe StackOverflow is an English-only site.

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/

Comment: Quiere que alguien lo traduce?

Answer (score 1):

The error says it all: `PreviousPage` is null.

Put a break point on this line to verify that and then go through your logic to see where you think you are instantiating `PreviousPage` to find out why it is not being instantiated.

The Visual Studio debugger is your friend.

Comment: @user2928647

El error dice todo: Previouspage esta null.

Ponga un punto de para en esta linea para hacer verdad. Despues hacerse seguro que haces una instancia PreviousPage para que sepas por que no hay una instancia.

Visual Studio debugger es su amigo

Answer (score 1):

You are not handling the posibility of a NullPointer. In this case **PreviousPage** is null.

To verify what is happening with your data use the Visual Studio Debugger.

Verify that your form is sending data correctly (your action attr.) and verify the method you are using (GET or POST).

If you want more help please post your code to see whats happening.